# git merge issuess - merge conflicts

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I am having this issues when im merging:

```
git pull origin dev
```

[produces conflicts in Python text, and in compiled  `__pycache__/*.pyc` files; I can handle the first] but IDK how to deal with others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other two files are pycache folders which you generally don't need. So unless for some reason you need them (which is unlikely), I would just delete those files and your conflicts should then be resolved after committing

Comment: In general, it's best to *avoid committing* compiled `*.pyc` files / `__pycache__` folders entirely.